# Can I use my iMac as a second display with my laptop, without a Thunderbolt port?

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, hdmi, thunderbolt-display

I have looked around the Internet for an answer to my specific problem, but can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for. I am trying to figure out whether it is possible to use my 21.5-inch mid-2011 iMac as a second monitor for my Windows 10 laptop.

The problem I am faced with, is that the iMac will only take input for Target Display Mode in the form of Thunderbolt, and my laptop does not have a Thunderbolt port, only HDMI. I have tried using an HDMI to Thunderbolt cable as well as an HDMI to Thunderbolt adapter with a regular HDMI cable. Neither of these worked, so unless my iMac's Target Display Mode isn't working, then the connection is the issue.

Is there any way I can connect my laptop to my iMac and use it as a second display?